# How can I adjust parameters for image processing algorithm in an efficient way?

Tags: java, statistics, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization

Before starting implementation of solution for my problem I just want to be sure if I will not “reinvent wheel” and if I can reuse work that someone have done before. So my problem is:

I have made image matcher using OpenCV library. This matcher receives a set of image files and trying to find similar images in database. At the end it returns statistical results according to [ROC Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) definition (True Positive, True Negative, False Positive and False Negative number of matches). These results can vary because of OpenCV’s library algorithm parameters values, which are about 10. This means that parameters adjustment will bring to more True Positive matches and to less False Positive matches. As I have to adjust more or less 10 parameters, brute force adjuster will be very slowly. By brute force I mean:

```
While(param1 < 50){
  While(param2 < 50){
    While(param3 < 50){
      …
      PerformMatching();
      param3 +=2;
    }
    param2++;
  }
  pram1 +=5;
}
```

What I want to do is to choose parameters randomly and then analyze if statistical results are becoming better. Then this analysis will help to alter method which is randomly generates parameters in order to choose better parameters.

So my question is if there is library in Java or if there is any AI algorithm, which will return better parameter set based on evaluation of True Positive and False Positive values?

Could appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hill Climbing

You could try some stochastic optimization algorithms, e.g., [Hill Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), in which you start with a random solution (like @Don Reba pointed out) and look at the set of neighboring solutions for those that are better with respective to the cost function. I will use some sample python code to explain the idea.

### Get neighbor solutions

For neighbors in your case, you can use a simple function like:

```
n_params = 5  # number of parameters
upper_bound = 5  # upper limit of your parameters
lower_bound = 0  # lower limit of your parameters

def get_neighbors(solution):
    neighbors = []
    for i in range(n_params):
        x = copy.deepcopy(solution)
        if x[i] < upper_bound:
            x[i] += 1 # increment one of the components
            neighbors.append(x)
        x = copy.deepcopy(solution)
        if x[i] > lower_bound:
            x[i] -= 1 # decrement one of the components
            neighbors.append(x)
    return neighbors
```

---

If you have a current solution of [1,3,4,2,2], by incrementing or decrementing any of the components, you get 10 different neighbors as below:

```
 [2, 3, 4, 2, 2],
 [0, 3, 4, 2, 2],
 [1, 4, 4, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 2],
 [1, 3, 5, 2, 2],
 [1, 3, 3, 2, 2],
 [1, 3, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 3, 4, 1, 2],
 [1, 3, 4, 2, 3],
 [1, 3, 4, 2, 1]
```

Here we assume every parameter is an integer. You could achieve more granularity by adjusting the step size (e.g., 0.05).

### Iterations of hill climbing

```
def hill_climb():
    initial_solution = np.random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound, n_params)
    current_solution = initial_solution
    print 'initial solution', initial_solution
    current_cost = get_cost(initial_solution)
    step = 1
    while True:
        #try to replace each single component w/ its neighbors
        lowest_cost = current_cost
        lowest_solution = current_solution
        print 'hill-climbing cost at step %6d: %d' % (step, lowest_cost)
        neighbors = get_neighbors(current_solution)
        for new_solution in neighbors:
            neighbor_cost = get_cost(new_solution)
            if neighbor_cost < lowest_cost:
                lowest_cost = neighbor_cost
                lowest_solution = new_solution

        if lowest_cost >= current_cost:
            break
        else: 
            current_solution= lowest_solution
            current_cost = lowest_cost
            step += 1
    return current_solution
```

### Cost function

For completeness, I will use my own cost function (just for a demo purpose), which is

```
f(x) = x1^1 - x2^2 + x3^3 - x4^4 + x5^5
```

That is :

```
def get_cost(solution):
    cost = 0
    for i,param in enumerate(solution):
        cost += (-1.)**i * param**(i+1)  
    return cost
```

### Optimization result:

Here is the result. We use a random initial guess of [4, 0, 1, 3, 1]. After 14 steps (evaluation of 14*10 = 140 neighbors), we find the optimal answer of [0, 5, 0, 5, 0] which minimize the cost. For brute force, you have to evaluate 6^6 = 46656 solutions. Much more running time could be saved while you have a high dimensional solution.

Note since this is a stochastic method, local minimum is found as the final result (though sometimes it's identical to the global minimum, it's not guaranteed). However practically it's good enough.

```
initial solution:               [4 0 1 3 1]
hill-climbing cost at step      1: -75
hill-climbing cost at step      2: -250
hill-climbing cost at step      3: -619
hill-climbing cost at step      4: -620
hill-climbing cost at step      5: -621
hill-climbing cost at step      6: -622
hill-climbing cost at step      7: -623
hill-climbing cost at step      8: -624
hill-climbing cost at step      9: -627
hill-climbing cost at step     10: -632
hill-climbing cost at step     11: -639
hill-climbing cost at step     12: -648
hill-climbing cost at step     13: -649
hill-climbing cost at step     14: -650
Final solution:                 [0 5 0 5 0]
```

### Related post

A related but more complex question is here: [Algorithm for selecting n vectors out of a set while minimizing cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953470/algorithm-for-selecting-n-vectors-out-of-a-set-while-minimizing-cost/12964153#12964153)

All codes above can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/4186012).

Answer (score 3):

There is a range of techniques for algorithm optimization, from the simple grid search in your example to various adaptive algorithms. If you want to learn about the more advanced techniques, I recommend starting by looking at [Frank Hutter](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hutter/papers.html)'s research. His [PhD thesis](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hutter/papers/Hutter09PhD.pdf) contains a great overview of the field.

If you don't want to spend too much time, one big improvement you could do is to generate your parameters randomly, instead of using a regular grid. This way, if some parameters turn out to be unimportant, you won't have wasted time keeping the other ones fixed. You want something like:

```
param1 = random.Next(50);
param2 = random.Next(50);
...
PerformMatching();
```

Another advantage of this approach is that you can collect sample points for as long as you want and not have to wait until the whole grid is explored. You can do still better by using a [quasi-random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) parameter sequence, which will keep the points evenly spread out. There are libraries that will generate these for you.

Once you have generated your points, you could simply choose the best combination, or analyze them using graphing tools or use a mode-finding algorithm, such as MeanShift.