# Realworld parameter optimization

Tags: java, optimization, parameters, machine-learning

I'm in the need to do parameter optimization for my latest research project. I have an algorithm which has currently 5 parameters (four double [0,1] and one nominal with 3 values). The algorithm uses those parameters to calculate some stuff and afterwards I calculate the Precision, Recall & FMeasure. A single run takes about 1,8s. Currently I'm going through each parameter with a 0.1 step size which shows me approximately where the global maxima is. But I want to find the precise global maximum. I've looked into Gradient Descent but I don't really know how to apply this to my algorithm (if it's even possible). Could anybody please guide me a little how I would implement such an algorithm since I'm very new to this kind of work.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Can you calculate a gradient for your (double) parameters?

Comment: Hi, Thomas. Had a look at your lib recently :) Currently my function looks like this: a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3 = y and x4 is a threshold-parameter which filters out answer where y < x4. But I don't know if this function does make any sense.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at genetic search algorithms http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm . There are also some Java implementations frameworks.

Comment: @DanielGerber hey thanks ;) Your function reduces to a normal linear combination and yields to a convex function (constrained by your intervals for double and your nominal value). So your gradients are basically the parameters itself so it should be no problem to minimize this with gradient descent (assuming you are choosing an appropriate value for alpha).

Comment: Which algorithm do you use? Gradient descent is not a so complex algorithm. If you look at logistic regression papers you will probably see gradient descent algorithm embedded to it. So you an port it.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut well, i think it's not that easy. the simple function a1x1+a2x2... determines a confidence for a given result. if this confidence is lower than x4 then the result is not used and should be left out of any further computation. Also I've just build this function like this so that I can see which parameters matter most. maybe there is a better function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do better than a grid search.

Before applying an algorithm like gradient descent, you have to be sure that your parameter space does not contain local maxima or that at least your starting point is close to the global maximum and your step size is appropriate enough to bring you to it.

In your case, I would recommend starting by drawing as many random samples as you can. This is a much better way of exploring the parameter space than a grid search. Once you collect enough data this way, you can use a mode-finding algorithm, such as [mean shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) or one of its faster derivatives, or go straight to optimization. Since you don't have the Jacobian of your parameter space, you could use the [Broyden's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%27s_method), which iteratively approximates it or a [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method), such as [BFGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFGS_method).

Also, see this related question: [How can I adjust parameters for image processing algorithm in an efficient way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644010/how-can-i-adjust-parameters-for-image-processing-algorithm-in-an-efficient-way)

Comment: thx don for your answer. I've had a look at the related question and implemented the hill climbing approach based on that. sadly it turned out that the function has a lot of local maxima (I think this is due to the threshold value). I sampled a lot of random starting points, so far the grid search gives me better results. is there a special way to deal with functions with lots of local maxima?